# Can "function" implement a protocol in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to make the function "type" implement a protocol in Elixir? I am playing around with a custom `Functor`protocol and was wondering if I could make functions implement it (ignoring all the limitations of Elixir's type system).

The implementation (if `function` where a type) would be

```
defimpl Category.Functor, for: function do
  def fmap(f, g), do: &(g.(f.(x))
end
```

Given that you could do

```
f_2x_plus_1 = &(&1 * 2) |> Functor.fmap(&(&1 + 1))
f_2x_plus_1.(1) == 3
```

Not that I'd use this for anything serious, just wondering.

Comment: Here's a category library in Elixir https://github.com/robot-overlord/witchcraft It might help to see what they've done.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can. Here is the implementation I am working on for what might result in a library called `excategory`

```
defmodule Category.Function do
  def compose(f, g) do
    arity_f = :erlang.fun_info(f)[:arity]
    arity_g = :erlang.fun_info(g)[:arity]

    case {arity_f, arity_g} do
      {1, 1} ->
        &(g.(f.(&1)))
      arities ->
        raise "Function are not of arity 1, got #{arities}"
    end

  end
end

defimpl Category.Functor.P, for: Function do
  defdelegate map(f, g), to: Category.Function, as: :compose
end
```

It was on the Protocol section of Getting Started

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html

Comment: So what does this get you?  I'm still not clear what syntax you are trying to enable.

Comment: @ChrisMeyer in Haskell (and Cathegory Theory) a function is a Functor (also an Applicative and a Monad). Useful or not I want to implement common Haskell Type Classes in Elixir using Protocols. I guess Monads wont be that popular en Elixir, but Monoids can be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me because there is only a single type of function in elixir, but Function is a type that you can 
implement protocols for.

```
defimpl Category.Functor, for: Function do
  def fmap(f, g), do: &(g.(f.(&1))
end
```

The problem that I see is that arity is very important in Elixir/Erlang and I don't see how to account for that in a straightforward way.

Comment: See my own answer. Its not ideal to check for arity by hand but I guess its the only way.

Comment: You can sometimes use Kernel.apply to work around arity problems.

Comment: Hmmm... but I don't think I can actually use `apply` because its function composition, you cant actually evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Because Erlang/Elixir are dynamically typed, the strict answer is no. Functions really are only differentiated by arity (or for named functions, module, function name, and arity).

You can specify more specific types via [Typespecs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/typespecs.html%20Typespecs), and dialyzer (usable in a mix task via dialyxer) will do some assertions on that, but this is not part of the compile toolchain or runtime and provides no guarantees. Not all the violations will be caught by dialyzer (it's based on success typing), but it's a good start.

Comment: I really don't need a guarantee about its arity. See the update.

Comment: I don't really know what about the answer would change, though. If you can't express it in typespecs, you've probably got nothing at all. If you can express it via typespecs, you can do tricks with macros to help yourself along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a `Protocol` for this... sorry if I've missed something important in your question.  You can implement a function with guards that does this though:

```
defmodule Functor do
  def fmap(f, g) where is_function(f) and is_function(g) do
    &(g.(f.(&1)))
  end
end
```

and then you can write:

```
iex> f_2x_plus_1 = Functor.fmap(&(&1 * 2), &(&1 + 1))
#Function<0.100612233/1 in Functor.fmap/2>
...> f_2x_plus_1.(1)
3
```

I guess I'm just not sure what the protocol gets you that a function doesn't.

Comment: In Haskell a Functor is a Type Class, not a concrete type. The best analogue in Elixir (and its working very well) is a Protocol. So I've been porting a bunch of these (Category Theoretical) Type Classes such as Functor, Applicative, Monad, Monoid, SemiGroup, etc. What a protocol gets me over a function is type-based dispatch and extensibility. The idea is that you create a library that handles say Monoids, you implement the Monoid Protocol for your custom struct/type and you can pass it to that module.